# CSS Making a content area full height + background image

Tags: css, background, gradient

Sorry for the stupid question. But how do you make a content area a full height of a browser window irrespective of how much content there is in it - i.e. some page could take up the whole area of the browser window (which is great!) but other pages might just have small amount of content and not enough to push all the way to bottom of the window.

Essentially I trying to apply a gradient shadow on the left and right hand side of the content area which would go all the way to the bottom of the page irrespective of how much content. I am trying to apply a css media query so that the shadow disappears if you have a smaller screen (i.e. it will only appear on desktop and not on mobile).

Also, some pages could have a header, others don't. Same applies to footer and finally some pages don't have either a header or footer so the height of the gradient needs to fit for all situations but in all cases there will always be a content area.

Some advice would be good.

Here are some example I am looking for:

Example 1: with Header and Footer
[image: Example 1: with Header and Footer]
Example 2: with Footer only
[image: Example 2: with Footer only]
Example 3: with Header only
[image]
Example 4: with no Header and Footer
[image]

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/upkrce5p/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#any_content{
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

It will set a minimum height for the content area.

Comment: Show me the HTML source, please (+CSS).